# CryptoLock issue with multiple instance of same binrary

Tags: c++, dynamic, g++, libssl

I am using

http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/threads.html

to make crypto library thread safe. It is working find if I am linking with static library of libssl and libcrypto.

But if I am linking with dynamic version of the library and running multiple instance of the binary it is crashing.

How to fix this issue ?

Edit

Program is always crashing at

```
#0  0x00007f9f42257be5 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#1  0x00007f9f4225820c in lh_retrieve () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#2  0x00007f9f4225ac8e in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#3  0x00007f9f4225bb41 in ERR_get_state () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#4  0x00007f9f4225c886 in ERR_clear_error () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#5  0x00007f9f44df496c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
#6  0x00007f9f44df6015 in Curl_ossl_connect () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
#7  0x00007f9f44e0a349 in Curl_ssl_connect () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
#8  0x00007f9f44de0950 in Curl_http_connect () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
#9  0x00007f9f44df12ba in Curl_protocol_connect () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
#10 0x00007f9f44df15b0 in Curl_connect () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
```

But while linking with static version, It is not crashing

Another bt

```
#0  0x00007f57a01b1be5 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#1  0x00007f57a01b20bf in lh_delete () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#2  0x00007f57a01b45b3 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#3  0x00007f57a01b5a5a in ERR_remove_thread_state () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#4  0x00007f57a2d4ffbb in Curl_ossl_close_all () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
#5  0x00007f57a2d47742 in Curl_close () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
```

Comment: Have you tried running the program in a debugger?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg  Added callback for the crash it is always crashing there randomly while linking with dynamic lib but some program is working with static version

Comment: It could be that libcurl doesn't use the thread-safe functions properly? Are you using libcurl in one thread and calls directly to libssl/libcrypto in another?

Comment: I am using libcurll in multiple thread (90) to access https content.

Comment: And you are using separate curl-handles in each thread I hope?

Comment: yes. I am using separate handle in each thread

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, just wanted to make sure! :)

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg no problem,  thanks for question:)

Comment: Is the locking callback being invoked when you link against the dynamic library?

Comment: I have similar issue (crash for dynamic OpenSSL library when cleaning thread) and I've [found some solution](https://github.com/opendnssec/SoftHSMv2/issues/239#issuecomment-248530242). I didn't tried it yet but it may help.